# Google play link in facebook shareDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am using "ShareDialog" for sharing a link from my app to Facebook wall. The link is the Google Play link. Also I am choosing the picture to be shown in my dialog.

When I post a dialog, it shows the link and the picture properly but not the description and the name that i have set in the dialog.

Kindly advice any fix for this

```
 new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
        .setName("Memory Game")
        .setPicture("http://i61.tinypic.com/jjbslv.png")
        .setDescription("The hello facebook") 
        .setLink("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?
               id=kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free");

   }
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this? The description automatically changed to "GET IT ON GOOGLE PLAY".

Comment: use like this "https://play.google.com/store/search?q=memory.game.collection.free&c=apps"